# XMAPP - PHP - Error 400

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

So, this question has probably been answered before but i have changed ports in my conf files which most other posts has not. I'm suspecting this is why it won't work.

So, first i had a problem where skype was using the ports xmapp used, so i changed them to : 8080 and 4433. I also changed server name to : localhost:8080 and www.example.com:4433

When i try to go to localhost:4433 using google chrome i get : 
Error 400
"Bad Request!, Your browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

And when i try with just localhost i get a white page.

And when i try t go to phpadmin "localhost/phpmyadmin"
it displays a white page.

Both mySql and Apache servers are running without any errors.
Any idea why and how to fix this problem? I've spent 15 hours now fixing 3 different errors.

Comment: white page = something blew up and you've got all debug options turned off. check your error logs, turn on `display_errors` and `error_reporting`.

Answer (score 0):

actually you have change this port at two places in httpd.conf file,i.e

1) Listen 80

2) ServerName localhost:80

at the above places the port value should be 4433, as per your changes

Comment: the above two places are enough to make the application work on the new port, first you need to stop and restart apache whenever you make the changes to httd.conf file, and try to make the skype run on another port other than 80

Comment: What if i already changed it in these files : xampp.conf, xamp-ssl.conf ?

Comment: revert every thing and just make the only two changes in httd.conf file

Comment: or remove (uninstall) xampp and try to re-install again, and try to make the changes, but before that, re-start your pc and shut-down the skype(exit).

Comment: So, i reinstalled XAMPP and changed the things you said, and now i get the skype is using port 443 error again : 20:40:12  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
20:40:12  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
20:40:12  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
20:40:12  [Apache]  Problem detected!
20:40:12  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" with PID 10256!
20:40:12  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

Comment: no issues, stop apache, now to go httpd.conf file and choose some any other port number like 81,82,83 etc and restart xampp

Comment: I changed all 443 ports in xampp to 8083 and now i don't get the error but still a white page.

Comment: Working now, changed webbrowser thing to localhost:8080

Comment: see happy, the installation of xampp and making a php file run is a simple task.So, just follow the steps, take fresh xampp, just change the port 80 to some other at only two places in httpd.conf file and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had this error start suddenly to my XAMPP instance on WIndows 7.

It started when I was doing a cleanup and removed a folder that was referenced as a redirect in the `.htaccess` file.

e.g.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If the folder `public` is removed/renamed, this error will start to occur, even with the simplest of PHP or HTML files being requested.

I fixed by removing the .htaccess - when I need it again I'll add it back in with the right paths.